# Problema de Redirecionamento https

Tags: nginx, redirecionamento

Estou com um problema um tanto quanto bizarro aqui.

Temos dois sites num mesmo servidor rodando com **Nginx**; um possui certificado `HTTPS` e o outro não. O problema é que se um cliente entre no site sem o certificado e coloca o `HTTPS` nele, o site é redirecionado para o outro domínio que possui o `HTTPS`. E se eu por acaso colocar o IP do servidor, como padrão ele vai pro domínio que não possui o `HTTPS`. No entanto, se colocar o `HTTPS` antes do IP também, o IP é redirecionado pro site que possui o `HTTPS`.

Me parece que alguma configuração padrão está fazendo o redirecionamento para o site com `HTTPS` e eu não estou conseguindo perceber o problema.

Comment: veja se essa questão do stack overflow en pode resolver: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773544/nginx-different-domains-on-same-ip

Comment: Poste a sua configuração.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que isso funcione.
Em php:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on'){
     $url = 'http://urldapagina.com.br' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
     header("Location: $url");
     exit; 
}
```

Comment: Na verdade a pergunta se refere ao Nginx, e não tem nada a ver com a implementação de um site ou outro. A pergunta é independente de linguagem.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Isso me lembra eu tentando resolver um problema com Nginx mal configurado (não tinha permissões para arrumar isso) usando arquivos *.htaccess*.